# Can't get ItemListener to work for JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing

I am using this code to create a JCheckBox

```
private final JCheckBox cbDisplayMessage = new JCheckBox("Display");

        cbDisplayMessage.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getItemSelectable() == cbDisplayMessage) {
                  if(cbDisplayMessage.isSelected()) { 
                     cbDisplayMessage.setSelected(false); 
                  } else {
                     cbDisplayMessage.setSelected(true); 
                  }


            }
        }
    });
```

When I run this it causes an StackOverflow error on setSelected(true). Can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any ideas appreciated....

Comment: You have to check if the event is initiated by human or not, because `setSelected` calls the same method again. Or do check against `System.currentTimeMillis()` and give yourself like 100ms as minimum offset to acknowledge change of state.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `ActionListener` instead of `ItemListener` as shown below without causing `StackOverflow` error.

```
cbDisplayMessage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (cbDisplayMessage.isSelected()) {
            cbDisplayMessage.setSelected(false);
        } else {
            cbDisplayMessage.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
});
```

There is no need to check the source of the event again because you are sure that you have added this listener on the same object. This is required only if same listener is added for more components.

---

-- EDIT--

**Now Your requirement is clear to me. If you want to toggle the state of the check box then there is no need to do it using listener because that's the default behavior of the check box.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I tried using an ActionListener already. When I use that, nothing happens when you click the check box. I thought you had to use ItemListeners with check boxes.

Comment: Now tell me what you want. as per your code you are restricting the user interaction. If it's selected then you are problematically setting it back to false. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, exactly, and if it's not selected, then I want to set it to true. Simple toggle of state...

Comment: Try with `ActionListener`

Comment: But can you tell me about toggle of state. Isn't it the default behavior of check box?

Comment: yes, it is the default behaviour of check box. I tried your updated post - it has no affect. The box does not un-tick.

Comment: **now you are making me confused. If you want to toggle the state then don't add any listener as simple as it is.**

Comment: Doh! I don't need a listener... thanks for your help. It works without any listener.

Comment: I'll update my post to make it clear for other who is doing in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is called every time the state changes, but you trigger a new state change from within that listener, so each state change results in that listener being called over and over again until your stack is full. Your setup has to be a bit more complicated to do something like that - if you want to change the state of the component you're listening to, you'll want to remove its listener(s), fire your programmatic state change, then re-add them.